# Running for loop in "parallel" using async/await promises

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise

I currently have a for loop like this:

```
async myFunc() {
    for (l of myList) {
        let res1 = await func1(l)
        if (res1 == undefined) continue

        let res2 = await func2(res1)
        if (res2 == undefined) continue

        if (res2 > 5) {
            ... and so on
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that func1, func2 are network calls which return promises, and I don't want them to block my for loop while waiting for them. So I don't mind working in parallel with myList[0] and myList[1], nor do I care about the order in which the items of the list are processed.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Instead of having them return a promise you could let em resolve/reject that promise and then just call them in the loop. If you don't want to process the responses.

Comment: It would be great to have some more code, to see if everything is setup right.
Usually you'll do something with `.then()` after waiting for a Promise, to be sure it runs in order.
You could then call another function with your second call in like so `.then((result) => {
callAnotherFunction(result); })`

Comment: @Frizzant - In an `async` function, you use `await` (as the OP did above), not `.then` (95% of the time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do it by writing a function that handles the one value that you're handling sequentially:

```
async function doOne(l) {
    let res1 = await func1(l);
    if (res1 == undefined) {
        return /*appropriate value*/;
    }

    let res2 = await func2(res1);
    if (res2 == undefined) {
        return /*appropriate value*/;
    }

    if (res2 > 5) {
        // ... and so on
    }
}
```

Then I'd use `Promise.all` with `map` to start all of those and let them run in parallel, getting the results as an array (if you need the results):

```
function myFunc() {
    return Promise.all(myList.map(doOne)); // Assumes `doOne` is written expecting to be called via `map` (e.g., won't try to use the other arguments `map` gives it)
    // return Promise.all(myList.map(l => doOne(l))); // If we shouldn't make that assumption
}
```

If `myList` is (or *may* be) a non-array iterable, use `Array.from` to get an array to use `map` on:

```
function myFunc() {
    return Promise.all(Array.from(myList.map(doOne)));
}
```

*(Or use a `for-of` loop pushing to an array.)*

If you don't want a failure to handle one entry in the list to prevent seeing the results from handling others in the list, use `Promise.allSettled` rather than `Promise.all`. (Note that they'll all be started **either way**, the only difference is whether you see the successful results when at least one of them fails.)